# Convert canvas contents into a canvas creatable image tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

On my canvas, I am creating a large number of objects and images, and once loaded, the program finds it hard to maintain this large quantity and frequently crashes. A solution I thought up would be to convert the canvas into an image (perhaps using `PIL`?), clear the canvas and use `canvas.create_image` to paste the image-form of the original canvas. I am aware, and have found in similar questions, there are ways to convert the image to a png file/save the file on the PC - I do not want this - I want to turn the image into a `PIL` image or tkinter `PhotoImage`.
How can I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: How many objects are you creating? In my experience the canvas can handle many thousands of objects. When the program crashes, do you get an error?

Comment: @BryanOakley >20,000 objects at least, the entire program stops responding upon any attempt of contact/movement